# how to resolve cyclic reference issue in asp.net core multi project solution

Tags: asp.net-core

I have solutions with layers(projects) like

Api-->Services-->DataAccess and Models project is common and referenced in all of them

now when I am trying to implement custom validation on one of the property in class in Models project, I am running in an issue that where to put the validator.

Validator has to access Service Layer to check if something exists in database.

if I put validator in API layer I can DI service but I cannot decorate the property with custom attribute since the property is in a class inside Models project and Model project is referenced in API project.

if I put validator in Models project then I cannot access Service Layer IContract as it is defined in Service layer and Service layer also reference Models layer.

any solution ?

Comment: ideally you should avoid cyclic dependency in any case. and also checking something in database for model validation also seems to be very costly operation. but if you really what to do this and want to avoid cyclic dependency then you can try to separate the model validation from model definition by using lib like [fluent validation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/tree/main/src/FluentValidation).